# Howto find internal IP server by external IP

Tags: domain, ip

I've got 12 servers in datacenter, but can login by SSH into one of them (facade server), other servers available only from it.
In **hosts file** we have ip list each of available servers.

```
milkov@devel:/var/www/davel$ cat /etc/hosts
192.168.1.4 data1
192.168.1.7 data2
192.168.1.5 bground1
192.168.1.6 bground2
192.168.1.10 frontend1
192.168.1.11 frontend2
...
```

Also I've domain megaplan.tvigle.ru (IP 79.142.100.36).

Question: How to know which one of servers serve this domain? How to find servers internal ip-address by external IP.

PS: Sorry about my Eng. lng

Answer (score 8):

> How to find servers internal ip-address by external IP.

You do not. Simple.

THis is like asking "how do I find out who is the owner of a fuel station based on the phone number of the next shop". No correlation.

Ineternal and External IP addresses are mapped by administrative decision - and that is it. Without access to the configuration file there is no way to get the relationship. Because there is no intrinsic one.

Comment: Thank you for response! But how can I find server which observe this domain, no how, just manual login into each server and exec ifconfig command?

Comment: No, sensible you would pick up the file where you keep records about this. Now yes, log into every file - and make sure that you actually write down this information. Record keeping is about half of your job.

Comment: Understood, Thx alot

Answer (score -5):

I'm sure you have a few servers that you suspect that could be serving this domain. What I suggest you do, is connect to those. After remoting in visit a site like www.whatismyip.com and it will show you the external IP mapped to that internal IP.
There are only 12 servers so should not take too long.

Comment: There are so many possible ways in which this won't work, there isn't enough space in a comment to list them all.

Comment: @Kuberan Whow. Correct. Fo example- you assume he degenerate case of a server having 1 IP only, which should be quite rare.